# HTML video does not load on Iphone from The same domain WordPress Website

Tags: iphone, wordpress, video, cross-domain

Videos won't load on iphone niether on safari nor on chrome if hosted on the same domain but,
It will load if the video is called from another domain :

The video is simply being called like this

```
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" controls="controls" width="300" height="150">
<source src="https://glistofficial.com/wp-content/themes/Glist/videos/pexels-shvets-production-9056559-3840x2160-50fps.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Here the video is called from the same domain

[Browser Stack Iphone 14 Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kn6.png)

Here the video is called from a different domain

[Browser Stack Iphone 14 Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeLD2.png)

Both of these domains have the same hosting,

on the live site I have a plugin for Optimization name 10 Web https://wordpress.org/plugins/tenweb-speed-optimizer/

I have tried calling the video from the live domain to other domains and It works there

[Browser Stack Iphone 14 Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf9b6.png)

I have tried removing lazyload scripts

I have tried using different videos and different video formats

There are no errors in console, The video returns a response of 200 in the Network tab but shows "Failed to load response data" in preview

[Browser Stack Iphone 14 Chrome Console Video Preview Tab Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/Nev99qOGW1CT.png)

[Browser Stack Iphone 14 Chrome Console Video Headers Tab Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/NdKGWHywYLO6.png)

Has anyone experienced this? This is not dynamic content as I had to upload the videos to my development server and call them here statically form the time bieng to look for a solution, but havent found anything

Comment: Is there anything useful for troubleshooting in the browser console log or network tab? It's a bunch of work to view that stuff, sad to say. [Read this](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-do-i-check-logs-on-ios-safari-if-i-use-windows.2373059/).

Comment: No related errors in console only getting "failed to load response data" in the networking tab for the video the response is 200 but preview shows failed to load response data

Comment: Hello Bro, pls change html like below:

<video preload="metadata" id="video-background" autoplay="" loop="" playsinline="" muted="">
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>